# Drupal 7 site maxing out memory when saving node

Tags: php, debugging, drupal-7

When saving a particular node, my Drupal 7 hits a WSOD and this shows up in the error logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 633339904 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes) in /var/www/mysite.org/includes/form.inc on line 1780, referer: http://mysite.or/node/193/edit
```

Saving other nodes, it appears to be a problem with this node. How can I figure out what function is maxing out the memory? How do you even begin to debug something like this? It would be more helpful if Drupal logged an error in watchdog but there's nothing there either.

PHP as you will see, has a generous 600M of allowed memory (this is a large site with 16GB of RAM).

Any ideas?

Comment: Any specific hints on what this node differentiates from others? Any particular modules this node uses?

Comment: Indeed 600M is quite generous. Do you have any images or large media content attached to this node? Do you have any custom modules on the site that might have a bug to cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You can, technically, catch the error in a shutdown function:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
  var_dump(error_get_last());
});
```

But it won't be very useful seeing that you already have the type, file and line where the problem is occurring. In practice, you'll usually want to follow what's going on by inserting `debug_backtrace()`, `var_dump()` and `die()` statements where needed.

Comment: This function, it's not drupal specific? and it is just called at the end of all my php functions automatically? Bloody awesome if that is the case!

Comment: Yeah, those are all standard php functions.